# How to Permanently Turn on SOLVER in VBA Reference?

Tags: excel, vba

SOLVER inside REFERENCE must be activated to enable SOLVEROK and SOLVERSOLVE in VBA, but VBA always turns off SOLVER automatically every time I quit Excel. How can I force activate SOLVER not temporarily but constantly? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you activate it manually? Sounds like you just need to have an addin.xlam that starts with excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should help, but the file directory, it depends of your Office version (in my case Office15)

```
Sub addsolver()
    Dim i As Long, x As Long

    x = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count

    For i = 1 To x
    'Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References(i).Name
        'check if Solver reference is already referenced
        If LCase(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References(i).Name) = "solver" Then
            MsgBox "Solver is already referenced"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next

    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\SOLVER\SOLVER.XLAM"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it would be better if this code is added to Personal.xlsb, so every time OP opens Excel, it would check for Solver, and it would be available all the time. Anyways, I upvoted your answer ;)