# Error "Can't add a reference to the specified file." for Excel 2016 SOLVER32.DLL Add-in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dllimport

I have been trying to import the excel Solver Add-in to VBA and am unable to do so. I can see the DLL file on my system when I click browse from the references in window in VBA (It isn't visible from the window). However, whenever I try to open the DLL file, it gives the the error message in the title. I am getting very frustrated that this is unable to work. I have tried moving the DLL file to other locations and calling it from there, but I am unable to. I have researched this problem, but nothing has resolved the issue. I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: Do you have the Solve Add-in enabled and, if so, is it working correctly?

Comment: Maybe that will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721661/how-to-permanently-turn-on-solver-in-vba-reference/57721993#57721993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBA reference that you need is to the solver add-in, which is the file `SOLVER.xlam`, and *not* to the DLL `SOLVER32.DLL`. The latter can't be directly added to a VBA project (I tried but also failed) but is doubtless called by the solver add-in behind the scenes.

If you have the solver add-in enabled, the reference to the Solver add-in should appear (relatively early) in the list of available references in the VBA editor. That you report not seeing it is strong evidence that you have not enabled the add-in (which can be done from the user interface under `File/Option/Add-ins`). Since you have been experimenting with moving folders around, you should be sure that they are in their default location, otherwise Excel might not know where to look for it when you try to install it.

Comment: So I had definitely enabled solver when I started working on the file as an .xlsx. But it must have been disabled when I converted the file to .xlsm. I went back and enabled solver again, and low and behold, what do I see in the references near the top, Solver! Tested the program and it works fine now. Thank you so much for the help!!